# How to populate a dropdown list from the database table in SugarCRM Community 6.5?

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu, sugarcrm

I've asked this question in the SugarCRM forums, but have been unable to find the answer as well. I am trying to populate a dropdown list in SugarCRM Community 6.5. I am using PHP5, MySQL and Apache. I created a custom dropdown list named 'oz_accounts' in the dropdown editor, created a new field in the custom module, Machines, that I built and associated the field with the Edit, Quick Create, Detail and List views based on the dropdown menu. Here is the code that I used, the result is a blank dropdown menu:

```
    <?php
    require_once('include/entryPoint.php');
    $db = & DBManagerFactory::getInstance();
    $myQuery = "SELECT name FROM accounts";
    $Result = $db->query($myQuery);
    $new_array = array();
    while($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($Result)) {
         $new_array[$row['key']] = $row['value'];
    }
    $GLOBALS['app_list_strings']['oz_accounts'] = $new_array;
```

Could someone please advise on what I'm doing incorrectly? I tested the query in phpmyadmin, and it retrieves the result i'm looking for, so I'm assuming that I must be making a mistake somewhere in the PHP code, possibly connecting to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted directions on how to do this here some time ago: http://www.eggsurplus.com/content/populate-a-dropdown-from-the-database/

What you need to do is to create a custom util function and then tell your vardefs for that field to call the custom util function.

```
//custom/Extension/application/Ext/Utils/getAccounts.php
function getAccounts(){
    static $accounts = null;
    if(!$accounts){
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM accounts";
        $result = $db->query($query, false);

        $accounts = array();
        $accounts[''] = '';

        while (($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result)) != null) {
            $accounts[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
        }
    }
    return $accounts;
}
```

Name of the file doesn't matter. Make sure to include opening PHP tags. Run a Repair/Rebuild so that it builds custom/application/Ext/Utils/custom_utils.ext.php.

Then in the vardef definition for that field set the function to getAccounts:

```
'function' => 'getAccounts',
```

Repair/Rebuild will be needed after the vardef change.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I've seen some of your work on the Sugar forums, but for some reason I never ran across this. That's what I needed!

Comment: @egg : link in your answer is dead. "Error 404 - Page not found!" can you please provide the updated link.

Answer (score 0):

the problems is in process definition the list not showing

Comment: Hi Liyo and welcome to SO. Answers are more likely to get accepted if you add some more detail, and present a minimal reproducible example of your solution as well.